# RVIZ rendering of overlapping objects

Tags: ros, rviz, pointcloud, opengl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

I have two (most likely) trivial questions about RVIZ but don't know what to search for.

1. How does RVIZ (or OpenGL?) act on objects, that are covered by others. Will this cost me performance? Let's say I have two very similiar, overlapping pointclouds, will double points be rendered twice, or recognize that?
2. Is there a possibility to downsample large pointclouds -only- during rotation/zoom/tilt? I know that from other tools and I am curious if there are any options in ROS/RVIZ?

Thanks for the info and best regards,

Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277353/rviz-rendering-of-overlapping-objects/) by [Laxnpander](https://answers.ros.org/users/29981/laxnpander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-12-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RVIZ uses the [Ogre](https://www.ogre3d.org/) rendering engine to display the 3D scene. It uses Z-buffering to correctly draw occluded objects, so every object is drawn whether it eventually ends up on the screen or not, so having two identical point clouds for example will take twice as longer to render since each point (a square billboard by default) is being rendered twice.

I've not seen any options to down sample point clouds in RVIZ during UI interactions as some viewers do. If you're working with really large point clouds and it's getting un-manageable then you could down sample them yourself and broadcast both the full and reduced clouds. This is a bit of a cludge but you could switch between them in RVIZ if the interface starts running too slow to use.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2017-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2018-01-23**:
There are ways to downsample clouds, for example by means of a voxel grid filter. See http://wiki.ros.org/voxel_grid